# Storing value in sql database to an variable in java

Tags: java, mysql

When I try to Enter details in my project It gives an error in the first try clause that reurned value from the database doesn't get inserted into local variable.
It seems the value is not parsed to an integer and gives an null value insted.

connector, preparedstatement,Resultset values are not defined here in my code but in the actuall programme thhey are connected properly.

*

```
int month = comb_month.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

try {
String sql1 = "SELECT SUM(hours) AS worksum FROM attandance WHERE month='" + month + "' AND userId='" + txtSearch.getText() + "'";
                System.out.println(sql1);
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    loggedinId.workinghours = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("worksum"));
                    System.out.println(loggedinId.workinghours);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
    try {
                String sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(hours) AS workdays FROM attandance WHERE month='" + month + "' AND userId='" + txtSearch.getText() + "'";
                System.out.println(sql2);
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    loggedinId.noWorkdayts = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("workdays"));
                    System.out.println(loggedinId.noWorkdayts);
                }
                int value = loggedinId.workinghours + loggedinId.noWorkdayts * 8;
                System.out.println(value);
                txtOverTime.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }

//loggedinId.workinghours and loggedinId.noWorkdayts are constent integer variables created in a seperate class
```

- 

[This is the error message dispayed in the programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VoAQ.png),
[This is the value in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vbyp.png)

It would be greate if anyone here can help me resolve my error.
Than you

Comment: I believe the one throwing the exception is `Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("worksum"))`, try changing it to `Double.parseDouble()` OR you could use `getDouble("worksum") `instead of `getString()`

Comment: also, they way you are using prepared statements is wrong, you shouldn't be using string concatenation but setting the parameters after creating the statement, take a look [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) or [check the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thank you @ozerobd,  *Double.parseDouble()* word and the value was successfully inserted into the textfield.

Comment: Thank you @ozerobd, I'll look through the documentation and try to correct my mistakes

Comment: No problem, glad I helped! ^^ Also check the solution I provided in the answer, it takes into account using PreparedStatement the intended way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I have modified the first try-catch block to make use of `PreparedStatement` functionalities, and changed that `parseInt(getString())` to a simple `getDouble()`, you can apply the same changes to the second block ;)

```
int month = comb_month.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

try {
    String sql1 = "SELECT SUM(hours) AS worksum FROM attandance WHERE month=? AND userId=?;";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    pst.setInt(1,month);
    pst.setString(2,txtSearch.getText());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        loggedinId.workinghours = rs.getDouble("worksum");
        System.out.println(loggedinId.workinghours);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```